# MySql LOAD DATA is ignoring my Primary Key id, and using autoincrement instead

Tags: mysql, load, auto-increment

I have a table that has a simple primary key, marked as auto_increment.

(Using MySQL 5.0.77) I do repeated LOAD DATA operations. I need to overwrite all of the data, with complete control over my primary key value.

LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "TopicInfile.dat" INTO TABLE Topic LINES TERMINATED BY "END-OF-THIS-RECORD";

The .dat file has the ID in it. It's not NULL. And yet, when I load this data, it behaves as if it was NULL, and assigns an autoincrement id, instead of using what I specified.

The only thing unusual about this .dat file is that it contains a lot of data. The .dat file has this structure:

```
1   2008-06-27 12:00:00 Type-Safe Enumerations  Énumérations    5   
...a lot of data here...
    \N  2002-10-01 12:00:00 END-OF-THIS-RECORD
2   2008-06-27 12:00:00 Class for constants Classe pour constantes  1   
...a lot of data here...
    \N  2002-10-01 12:00:00 END-OF-THIS-RECORD
```

and so on

The table structure is :

```
CREATE TABLE `Topic` (
  `Id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `LastEdit` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `TitleEnglish` varchar(75) NOT NULL default '',
  `TitleFrench` varchar(75) default NULL,
  `ChapterId` smallint(6) NOT NULL default '0',
  `BodyEnglish` text NOT NULL,
  `BodyFrench` text,
  `CreationDate` datetime NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`Id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=251 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

I have other tables for which the behavior is fine - the LOAD DATA operation always accepts my id value, except for the above Table.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: What is the delimiter character in `TopicInfile.dat`?

Comment: The records are delimited by the text: "END-OF-THIS-RECORD" Do you mean the new line character?

Comment: I meant what is the column delimiter, not the row delimiter.

Comment: Columns are delimited by tab characters.

Comment: I guess the real question is : how does one correctly load data when the data is large, and has multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why the items were treated as null.

I made some changes to the content of the input file (tab characters not quite right), and to the LOAD DATA command (EOL character not right), which is now behaving correctly:

See:
[MySQL LOAD DATA with multiline data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7067672/mysql-load-data-with-multiline-data)